# Using Count distinct case in sql and group by multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a query that works great (listed below). The issue I am having is we have run into a patient that has had event on two different days and because I am grouping by the `PATNUM`, it is only showing it as one.

How can I get it to count 1 for each time if the `PATNUM` and `SCHDT` are different

Example:

```
      PATNUM    SCHDT
      12345      30817
      12345      30817
      54321      30817
      54321      30717
```

`PATNUM 12345` should only count once while `PATNUM 54321` should count twice.

My count statement is this:

```
SELECT ph.*, pi.*, 
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `SERVTYPE` IN ('INPT','INPFOP','INFOBS','IP') AND Complete ='7' THEN pi.PATNUM ELSE NULL END) AS count1,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `SERVTYPE` IN ('INPT','INPFOP','INFOBS','IP') AND Complete ='8' THEN pi.PATNUM ELSE NULL END) AS count2
FROM patientinfo as pi 
INNER JOIN physicians as ph ON pi.SURGEON=ph.PName 
WHERE PID NOT IN ('1355','988','767','1289','484','2784')  
GROUP BY SURGEON 
ORDER BY Dept,SURGEON ASC
```

Comment: In most enterprise SQL engines this would throw an error. You should be grouping by ALL the fields which are not part of the aggregate functions. This must be mySQL or some engine which supports a non-standard group by syntax.  Add to your group by patnum and schdt and you may be close but I would still be afraid of the other data in patentinfo and physicians which isn't grouped.

Answer (score 1):

Which columns do you want to see?

You can adjust your GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
ph.pname,
ph.specialty,
SUM(CASE WHEN complete = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) count1,
SUM(CASE WHEN complete = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) count2
FROM 
(
  SELECT
  DISTINCT
  surgeon,
  patnum,
  schdt,
  complete,
  servtype
  FROM patientinfo
  WHERE complete IN (7,8)
  AND servtype IN ('INPT','INPFOP','INFOBS','IP')
  AND pid NOT IN ('1355','988','767','1289','484','2784')  
) pisub
INNER JOIN physicians ph ON pisub.surgeon = ph.pname 
GROUP BY ph.pname, ph.specialty
ORDER BY ph.pname, ph.specialty;
```

Also, I would make a few suggestions:

- If you're going to give your tables an alias, then use the alias when referring to any column in your query. I've made a guess here about some of your columns as to which table they come from (e.g. dept), so feel free to change it if it is not correct
- You don't need to select all records from both tables if you don't need them
- The query won't run if you don't GROUP BY all columns you're selecting. [I've written about this](http://www.databasestar.com/oracle-group-by) for Oracle and SQL in general, but actually in MySQL I think it does run but show incorrect results.

Comment: mySQL (and a few other engines) extends the group by so that it picks a value from a non grouped by field.  This is BY DESIGN thus a feature, so not incorrect results; one just has to understand what it does and why. which is different than most enterprise level databases.

Comment: If I group by date and surgeon it gives a line for each date and surgeon so I would have 20 lines for each surgeon each month. I'm looking for one line per surgeon showing how many cases they did.

And I am open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: If you want one line per surgeon and the count of cases, then it would be GROUP BY surgeon and only show the surgeon. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The output is
ph.Specialty  ph.pname, Count where complete = 7, Count where complete = 8

Comment: OK - I've updated the answer to match. Is this what you're after? Note that your recent comments says you don't want the surgeon field and you want the speciality and pname fields.

Comment: With your suggestion, I am getting the same result as before.... it is only counting each PATNUM once even if they are on different dates.

Comment: I see. I have updated the answer now. I tested it by creating some dummy data on my own database and running it. Is this what you are after? The subquery gets the data you want to calculate, and the SUM totals those records for your count.